# Can I access my iCloud account even after resetting my phone?

Tags: icloud

I am switching from an iPhone to an Android. I dont have the time to transfer everything right now but am letting a friend borrow my iPhone. If I reset my phone, can I still access all my info from iCloud even if a new iCloud account is set up on my old device?

Comment: ty for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the content on iCloud is separate from any particular device (except Backup) and can be accessed from a different device regardless of what happened to the original. You won't be able to access all your iCloud data without an iPhone or Mac though (e.g. Safari History and other app data).

Comment: ty fo your help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as you everything has been backed up to iCloud. After you get your iPhone back from your friend, you can remove the iCloud account, put your one back in, and choose to sync everything when prompted.